# How to take text from file?

Tags: python, file

I'm a beginner in Python, and I don't get how to take a text from a file.

I've tried a lot of codes that I found on this forum, but it seems that no one tried to do what I'm trying to do.

It's been 3 days I'm trying to do that and I feel like It's impossible.

Here is the code, I have a file named 1.txt and I'm wondering how to get the content of 1.txt right here : """Text from my file here"""

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

```
def analyze_text_sentiment(text):
   client = language.LanguageServiceClient()
   document = language.Document(content=text, type_=language.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT)

   response = client.analyze_sentiment(document=document)

   sentiment = response.document_sentiment
   results = dict(
       text=text,
       score=f"{sentiment.score:.1%}",
       magnitude=f"{sentiment.magnitude:.1%}",
   )
   for k, v in results.items():
       print(f"{k:10}: {v}")

from google.cloud import language


def analyze_text_entities(text):
   client = language.LanguageServiceClient()
   document = language.Document(content=text, type_=language.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT)

   response = client.analyze_entities(document=document)

   for entity in response.entities:
       print("=" * 80)
       results = dict(
           name=entity.name,
           type=entity.type_.name,
           salience=f"{entity.salience:.1%}",
           wikipedia_url=entity.metadata.get("wikipedia_url", "-"),
           mid=entity.metadata.get("mid", "-"),
       )
       for k, v in results.items():
           print(f"{k:15}: {v}")
           

text = """Text from my file here"""
analyze_text_sentiment(text)
analyze_text_entities(text)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand what *problem you are encountering* with the code, because there is a lot of code that seems to have nothing to do with reading a file (or trying) and none that does try. You say that you "have tried a lot of codes you have found on this forum", but a) this **is not a discussion forum**; b) we don't know **what** code you tried; c) we don't know **how** you tried it. So there is no way we can possibly know what went wrong. "Here is the code, I have a file named 1.txt" Okay. **What does the code have to do with** the file?

Comment: The way that you get text from a file is the same way no matter what you want to do with that text, so all the rest of the code is not relevant to the problem. There is nothing we can possibly tell you about how to read text from a file, because there is a specific way to do it, it has been explained many times already, and there is no way we can figure out what went wrong when you tried it. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592 and [mre].

Comment: As a side note, reading a text file is a fundamental task. You should learn about how to do this kind of thing by *following a tutorial for the Python language, start to finish*, first, before trying to design your own projects. Especially if you want to work with sophisticated libraries like the Google Cloud API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to open the file and read it. Assuming the 1.txt file is in the same directory you run your python script from:

```py
with open("1.txt") as f:
    text = f.read()

analyze_text_sentiment(text)
analyze_text_entities(text)
```

The `with open(...) as f` context manager implicitly closes the file for us, even if we experience errors inside the block, always use it to read files.

Documentation for `open` can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).